# Neural Network Classification Probelm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

How can 2-layer networks be used to classify more than two categories?

Can it be done just by adding more units/nodes into the existing layers?

Answer (score 1):

I think the 2-layer neural network can be used to classify two or more class problem. It does not depend on the number of nodes of each layer. The problem you want to solve (i.e., the dataset you work on) decides how many classes you have.

For more, see [here](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/multi-class-neural-networks/one-vs-all), [here](https://stackabuse.com/creating-a-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-multi-class-classification/), [here](https://chrisalbon.com/deep_learning/keras/feedforward_neural_network_for_multiclass_classification/) or [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/neural-networks-machine-learning-tutorial/).